# Cannot update or delete tenant app in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a Microsoft app which we created, installed on our tenant (tenant app, not sideloaded).

I cannot:

- Uninstall the app
- Update the app with a new version number

I have all permissions to do so and my account is the installing account.
The manifest was built using App Studio.

I also have a related problem: the app is still usable even though it is not installed in any team. The app does not appear in the "Personal apps" tab or the Applications tab when clicking the three dots in the left side panel of Microsoft Teams.

Permissions:

[image: Setup permissions]
[image: App permissions]
[image: Org-wide settings]

Manifest:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
"manifestVersion": "1.5",
"version": "1.0.2",
"id": "<APP_ID>",
"packageName": "com.heyaxel.axel",
"developer": {
    "name": "HeyAxel",
    "websiteUrl": "https://heyaxel.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.heyaxel.com/files/Privacy_Policy.pdf",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.heyaxel.com/files/Privacy_Policy.pdf"
},
"icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
},
"name": {
    "short": "Axel",
    "full": "Axel"
},
"description": {
    "short": "Axel offers new hires perfect success conditions and saves managers' time",
    "full": "Axel is a virtual assistant who offers the perfect success conditions to your new hires while saving time for busy managers.\nAxel transforms best onboarding practices into automated processes in your organisation. He helps managers:\n- Engage with their new hire before their arrival\n- Set tangible goals and monitor their progress\n- Save time by automating recurrent tasks, such as scheduling meetings\nOn average, Axel reduces the time-to-productivity of new employees by a third."
},
"accentColor": "#F9F9FA",
"bots": [
    {
        "botId": "61510758-1c2d-468f-ba41-6890b788fa16",
        "scopes": [
            "team",
            "personal"
        ],
        "supportsFiles": true,
        "isNotificationOnly": false
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
],
"validDomains": [
    "<ALLOWED_DOMAINS>"
]
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [Manage app permissions policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-setup-policies). Could you please share your manifest too..

Comment: Yes, I know this documentation. We changed the settings several times to test them about 10 days ago. I have attached the current permissions & manifest.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Do you know how I can get help on this? This makes development and testing extremely difficult.

Comment: Could you please check Microsoft Teams channel is added while creating your Bot? Could you please also share your bot id so we can check it on our end?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Okay, I have added the bot ID to the manifest above. Note that more than one app / bot is bugging like this. I don't understand what you mean by "Microsoft Teams channel is added while creating your bot"

Comment: Could you please try to create a new bot and update the bot id in your manifest? We have tried at our end and it working fine in teams the issue is with your bot id. Please take a look at [Create a Bot](https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new).

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Changing our bot ID has implications, the bot is used in production by several customers. Is there really no alternative? This is only occurring in our tenant, not customer tenants.

Comment: Did you tried to add App ID as Bot Id in your manifest?

Comment: Did you tried following steps?, We have tested your manifest at our end and it is working fine, The issue is with your tenant settings. Please take a look at [Use office365 admin portal to manage admin portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/tenant-apps-catalog-teams#use-the-office-365-admin-portal-to-manage-the-tenant-apps-catalog).

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Can you explain what it means to "add App ID as Bot Id" in the manifest? I don't understand what the issue may be with my tenant settings, I have provided screenshots, what could be the problem? Note that the "Use portal" instructions provided in your link are out of date, Teams admin is managed somewhere else now (that's where I took the screenshots)

Comment: Bot Id is specific to bot which is unique when a bot is created, You can assign Bot id as App Id, We 'have tested your app manifest at our end, it is working fine , I would suggest to debug your bot in emulator first if needed please create a new bot,

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Thank you for testing the manifest. Yes, I know it works, it's installed on several environments. The issue is that *our* tenant is not working correctly, with an app that is impossible to delete, impossible to upgrade and impossible to reinstall. Is there no way to get rid of this bugged application? Recreating an app is a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: Could you please try to delete app from your teams admin portal, where your tenant is registered?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Thanks Trinetra, unfortunately I don't know where to do that. I can block its usage, but I can't find any option to delete it. Could you give me pointers please?

Comment: Go to Office 365 Admin center => Azure Active Directory = >App Registration. Search your Bot Application and delete it from there.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Thanks but that would not just remove the app from my tenant, it would delete the entire app from Azure AD! That isn't a viable solution to me, the app is in production on customer tenants.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? Could you please try to login in that tenant where app is installed and remove it from there?

Comment: Yes I am :( I don't know where I can "remove" an app in the Office portal. I can only "Block apps", not "remove" them. In Teams, the same error as usual: "An error has occurred"

Comment: The user needs to go to desktop and uninstall the app from Teams. We do not have a mechanism currently to uninstall on mobile.